# Number of Ranges that lie completely in a particular Range

Tags: algorithm

Let us say we have n  ranges each specified by

```
 [l_i,r_i] where 1<=i<=n
```

And we have a query of type [L,R] in which we have to find the number of ranges among those n ranges that lie **completely** in the given range i.e. [L,R]

Example:

n ranges are:

here n is 2.

```
2 4
3 3
```

for query 3 5, output should be 1.

for query 2 5 output should be 2.

I know method for O(m*n), where n is number of ranges and m is number of queries, but feels like there must be a more efficient implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The data structure that you want is called an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 0):

For the following solution each query has complexity O(log(n)) but it requires to store (n^2/2) ranges and preprocessing requires to sort the ranges (complexity O(n*n log(n)) using quicksort):

Preprocessing:

1. Sort the n ranges by L_i
2. For each range [L_i,R_i]:

   a) find the subset S_i of all ranges [L_j,R_j] for which L_j >= L_i is true.

   b) sort S_i by R_j

Query [L,R]:

1. Find the S_i with the smallest L_i so that L_i >=L using binary search (complexity O(log(n)). S_i contains all candidate ranges.
2. Find in S_i the largest R_j so that R_j <= R again using binary search. The index of this entry corresponds to the number of ranges which satisfy your condition.

Lets get back to your example:
S_1: [3 3] [2 4] 
S_2: [3 3]

1. query 3 5 ends up in S_2. Apparently, there is one entry satisfying also the second condition
2. query 2 5 ends up in S_2. The second entry is the largest one satisfying the R condition and thus the result is 2